# Computing $I=\int_0 ^{2\pi}\frac{dx}{(a+b\cos x)^2}$

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-explanation

> Compute the integral using residues:
>
> $$I=\int_0 ^{2\pi}\frac{dx}{(a+b\cos x)^2}$$

Resolution(book):

$I=2\pi i\sum_{|z_k|<1}res_{z=z_k}f(z)$

where $f(z)=\frac{4z}{i(bz^2+2az+b)^2}\\z_1=\frac{-a+\sqrt{a^2-b^2}}{b}\:\:\text{and}\:\:z_2=\frac{-a-\sqrt{a^2-b^2}}{b}$

In $D(0,1)$ there is only a pole of order 2:$z=z_1$

$res_{z=z_1}=\frac{4}{i}\frac{d}{dz}(\frac{z(z-z_1)^2}{b^2(z-z_1)^2(z-z_2)^2})=\frac{a}{i(a^2-b^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}}$

Then:

$I=\frac{2\pi a}{(a^2-b^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}}$

**Questions**:

How does the author derives the function  $f(z)=\frac{4z}{i(bz^2+2az+b)^2}$? What is the technique behind it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $z=e^{ix}$ and then $dz=izdx$ and $\cos\theta=\frac12(z+\frac1z)$. So
\begin{eqnarray*}
I&=&\int_0 ^{2\pi}\frac{dx}{(a+b\cos x)^2}\\
&=&\int_{|z|=1}\frac{1}{(a+\frac{b}{2}(z+\frac1z))^2}\frac{dz}{iz}\\
&=&\int_{|z|=1}\frac{4z}{i(2z+b(z^2+1))^2}dz.
\end{eqnarray*}